# Create site using Custom Template in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template

After creating site collection using `Select Template Later` option, I uploaded a custom `.wsp` for site and activated the feature. After that, I can't see the custom tab for selecting the custom template.

Can anybody guide me on what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the **language** of the original site (which was saved as the site template).

By default, the blank site temple use (`< Select template later … >`) is using **English** as the site language. 
[image]

Make sure the language of the new site collection is the **same** as the language of the original site.